# Number of elements of a finite set in at least two subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ are subsets of a finite set, how many elements are in **at least** two of the subsets?

currently, I think I am trying to find $|(A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ C) \ (A ∩ B ∩ C)|$. is this correct so far? or am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: would you not have to subtract $A∪B∪C$ twice since you've counted the intersection three times in total and you only want to count it once. maybe try aiming for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Drawing out the ven-diagram can help with small numbers of sets.

[image]

You want to include all the elements in the green and yellow sections, and none in the red sections. To start with, consider:

$|A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |A \cap C|$

This gets each green section once, but counts the yellow section three times. So, we need to subtract out the yellow section twice which leaves us with:

$|A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |A \cap C| - 2 \times |A \cap B \cap C|$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you think about all the possible subsets of the union $A \cup B \cup C$, they are the followings:

(i) $A - (B \cup C)$

(ii) $(A \cap B) - C$

(iii) $B - (A \cup C)$

(iv) $(A \cap C) - B$

(v) $(A \cap B \cap C)$

(vi) $(B \cap C) - A$

(viii) $C - (A \cup B)$

You need to find element which appears in at least two sets. Thus, you need count (ii) - (iv) - (v) and (vi) in the above list.